# can not export gltf with build modifier

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have an animation with build modifier and position changing.[image]

I drag the gltf file to the glTF Viewer.
But the animation not contains the build modifier animation.
[image]
There is only position changing.
How to export the build modifier animation.

glTF exports in this parameter
[image]

Comment: I'm not experienced ...but when I don't know how to get out anim I use alembic format ...

Comment: I need to show the animation in web.I don't know whether the alembic format can be showed in web

Comment: No, it was meant to use alembic as intermediate format to translate modifiers anim to something readable to other formats. But what I tried now - export to abc, import abc, export as gltf, import gltf ... didnt work either. Sorry my inputs :)

Comment: The easiest way is probably [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/quill-vr-animation-to-glb/18668/6).

Comment: @scurest It works. But when the big data loaded,it will get stuck.

Comment: It ignores the build modifier probably because it is Blender specific and gltf format doesn't recognize it.